# Getting a download prompt due to response mixed up from two requests

Tags: browser, http-headers

I have 4 iframes in my page whose src's change as I scroll down my web page. The faster I scroll the src's change more frequently. If I scroll fast enough I get a download prompt in FF.

The downloaded file contains garbled text followed by http response headers and then more garbled text. When I capture this on ethereal I see that the browser wrote the request headers before one of the responses completed and then the server completed the response for the un-finished response then the response headers followed by the response of the intermediate request.

This happens on IE too, instead of getting a download prompt I get garbled text in one of my iframes.

Where does the bug lie on the client side or the server , How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe taking usage of some kind of queue.

If you're using jquery you might try this plugin:

[jquery-ajaxq](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq)

greetings